# Query with where condition on the filestream blob table never returning only on some servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

**strong text**aI have a query that returns at most one row from a table with a `FILESTREAM` column, using the following condition:

```
select * from TABLE_WITH_FILESTREAM_BLOBS
where BLOB IS NULL AND ID_BLOB = 99
```

However, this query never returns when executed on certain databases. If I remove the `BLOB IS NULL` condition, the query returns as expected:

```
select * from TABLE_WITH_FILESTREAM_BLOBS
where ID_BLOB = 99
```

I suspect that the problem is related to the large number of records in the table, and that the server needs to read all the blobs to be able to return a valid response.

Are there any server settings that I can adjust to avoid this issue? Or is it simply not possible to use `WHERE` clauses on `FILESTREAM` columns in a performant way?

My goal is to let the server return, otherwise my applications is stuck.

**UPDATE:**
the query is like this

```
(@P0 int)SELECT ID_BLOB, BLOB_DATA FROM MY_BLOB_TABLE
WHERE ID_BLOB= @P0 AND BLOB_DATA IS NULL
```

so it is a parametric query, could it be that because of being parametric a full table scan is triggered even there is a condition to restirct the seacrh to only one record (`WHERE ID_BLOB= @P0`)?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be causing the engine to load the whole file for each row. A filtered index might be useful `CREATE INDEX IX_Nulls ON TABLE_WITH_FILESTREAM_BLOBS (ID_BLOB) WHERE (BLOB IS NULL)`. Please show the full table definition, and share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: thanks for the reply. In fact i rechecked and the query is select ID_BLOB, BLOB_FIELD where ... so even the index, who would solve the issue is a problem. THe query should not be done, since the query is done by a framework i must report the issue to the framework vendor since i have no control on it, the query moreover is useless, so it is a framework bug. Honestly this question is hopeless, you can anyway answer and i will aceept it. thanks

Comment: I studied a bit more and i reazlied the query is a parametric one, check the UPDATE part at the end of the question. Thanks!

Comment: I repeat: **Please show the full table definition including indexes, and share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com**

Comment: ok, here it is https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkVLyN0Jh i do not know how  to see a execution plan of a parametric query. the query in fact is parametric.

Comment: That plan has nothing to do with either query that you were asking about. You can just declare the parameters as variables and you should get a similar query plan `DECLARE @P0 int; SELECT ID_BLOB, BLOB_DATA FROM MY_BLOB_TABLE
WHERE ID_BLOB= @P0 AND BLOB_DATA IS NULL` also please show table and idnex definitions